# Bibliography for Multivariable Calculus from a Topological Point of View

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, physics, book-recommendation

I will be teaching a Multivariable Calculus undergraduate course soon. Usually, this course is taught through bibliography such as Marsden's and Tromba's "Vector Calculus" or Wood's "Advanced Calculus", which are great, but I would love for my class to be a bit more broad and challenging. Specifically, I would love for the class to be oriented, just enough, since it is mainly for physics undergrads, to (differential) geometry and topology. In particular, I think about Nakahara's "Geometry, Topology, and Physics" when I think about how to introduce the notion of a vector, an inner and outer product, reference frames, and all of those things. I believe you shouldn't wait until grad school and to decide you want to do gravity or mathematical physics in order to understand what a tensor is, and I'd like my course to be an introduction to those concepts.

Hence, before I start writing my own notes, I was wondering if someone knows any bibliography which boards multivariable calculus' topics in such a manner without being too advanced, such as Nakahara's. I've already looked at some and asked for my colleagues' recommendations and nothing close to what I'm looking for has popped out.

Comment: If you’re eventually looking towards Nakahara, then why not the classics by Spivak/Munkres/Loomis and Sternberg?

Comment: This book goes into geometry, but it is a bit terse and should be supplemented with a book like Lee's Manifold Books: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Comment: If you want to provide value for your physicists' then you should focus on coordinates and the metric. That's what they permanently need and learn. Physics is the art of coordinate manipulation. That is Euclidean in the case of the spaces and connections in the case of differential geometry. Topology isn't really what they need, at least not without frames to measure things. The most abstract useful concept I can think of is Noether's theorem.